# Как прочитать один символ из консоли?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, консоль

У меня есть программа:

```
char getChar() {
    return /*smth*/;
}

printf("INPUT: ");
char chr = getСhar();
printf("OUTPUT: %c", chr);
```

...и проблема: что должна возвращать `getChar`? Мне нужно, чтобы после нажатия кнопки на клавиатуре нажатый символ *немедленно* был прочитан. Вариант по сути 1 - `getchar` (не путать с `getChar` - `getChar` - моя функция, а `getchar` - функция из `stdio.h`). Но при его использовании я могу ввести более 1-го символа, например:

```
INPUT: qwerty1234567890
OUTPUT: q
```

Я знаю, что такая функция есть в .NET (`Console.ReadKey`), и, взглянув на её реализацию, понял, что здесь нужен WinAPI и функция `ReadConsoleInput`. Вот как её использую я (без проверок):

```c
char getChar() {
    INPUT_RECORD inputRecord; // запись о введённом символе
    unsigned long readedCharCount; // кол-во прочитанных символов

    ReadConsoleInput(
        GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), // возвращаем дескриптор ввода консоли
        &inputRecord,
        1,
        &readedCharCount);

    return inputRecord.Event.KeyEvent.uChar.AsciiChar; // извлекаем из записи нажатый символ
}
```

Но когда я запускаю программу выше (`getchar` -> `getChar`), происходит неописуемое. Если запускать по-шагово, то при входе в функцию `ReadConsoleInput` программа зависает и я не могу ввести ничего в консоль. Если же поставить breakpoint после данной функции, то консоль мне не даст ввести символ, и можно обнаружить, что `inputRecord.EventType == 16`, а должно равняться `1` (`KEY_EVENT`). Причём нет ни одного `xxx_EVENT`-макроса со значением `16`! Как это понимать, и что я делаю не так?

Comment: В **стандарте С** такой функции нет, там ввод буферизован. Это для понимания при использовании `_getch()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`16` в `INPUT_RECORD.EventType` - это `FOCUS_EVENT`, что естественно, ведь при переключении с отладчика на консоль она первым делом получает фокус ввода. Нужно просто пропускать все ненужные события при чтении:

```
WORD ReadKey(HANDLE hInput) {
    INPUT_RECORD ir; DWORD t;
    while (ReadConsoleInput(hInput, &ir, 1, &t)) {
        if (ir.EventType != KEY_EVENT) continue; // игнорируем все события, кроме KEY_EVENT
        if (ir.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown) return ir.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode;
    }
    return 0; // возвращаем 0 в случае ошибки ReadConsoleInput
}
```